# Ruby on Rails - any performance diagnostic tools?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I've got some serious issues with my app on production server and I need to check how mysql is loaded in real time. I would like also to know how many queries is made on every page reload (sometimes at footers people are displaying queries count and time of generated page).

Is there any gem or piece of code to check performance on Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Problem solved - https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newrelic - http://newrelic.com/

Comment: I forget to mention that I am looking for free tools

Comment: newrelic is free when running on localhost, it won't show you what is actually happening in production but will show you what sql is running on each page and how long it is taking - I recommend you go that route first?

Comment: You are absolutly right. I've just get scared when I saw Pricing section at their website. I tried https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug and it's simply amazing tool. Its also free of charge even on production server

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick google search and found [RubyRun](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/RubyRun-44013.shtml), [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/ign). I'm sure you are asking for recommendations, but I haven't used these.
I think New Relic looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your help. New Relic looks nice but it's not free ;(